# how do you see what traffic is being forwarded to a static route?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

I have Juniper SRX

I created this static route (in inet.0):

```
10.123.123.0/24      *[Static/5] 21:52:24
                    > to 192.123.123.100 via ge-0/0/2.0
```

How do I view what traffic is being forwarded via that static route? I tried to monitor traffic with this command but it has no output:

```
monitor traffic interface ge-0/0/2.0 matching "net 192.123.123.100"
```

I know traffic is going there because I have devices pinging addresses in 10.123.123.0. Is my command wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the filter `matching "net 192.123.123.100"` only shows the traffic *directed to the gateway itself* (on the IP level).

Instead, you'd need to filter `matching "net 10.123.123.0/24"` to see traffic destined there.

The filter is applied to packets that are passing through the interface - however, they're not carrying the gateway's IP address but their original source and destination addresses (unless NAT is in use).

The gateway's address is just used to determine the L2 destination of the current hop, but it's completely invisible in the IP packet at hand.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to monitor ALL interfaces too? if I leave interface blank it monitors st0

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with Junipers - it's quite possible that you can only monitor a single interface at a time, or turn on monitoring for each individually, or you might be able to use `all` (unlikely though).